# Regex to match vim swap files and other temporary files like "*.swp" and swx

Tags: regex

I have a bash script that uses inotifywait to copy files that are created in a directory.

But it is copying vim temporary files that I don't want.

E.g. if I create `foo.txt` and edit it in vim, I end up with some/all of these:

```
foo.txt~
.foo.txt.swp
.foo.txt.swx
4913
```

I'm trying to write regex to match those and this is what I have so far:

```
'^\*\.sw??$'
```

I was hoping that would at least match the swp and swx files but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

```
^.+?\.sw.?$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^ Start of string
.+? - Matches any character 1 or more (non greedy)
\. - matches literal .
sw.? - Matches sw followed by 1 character
$ - End of string
```

Comment: Why not use asterisk instead of ".+?" ? Or ".*"?

Comment: @ButtleButkus Would mean the same thing here, but that would also match files like `.swp`. That is some *hidden* file you probably don't want to match. So I changed it.

Comment: Makes sense but for some reason your regex didn't work and juergen's did. Except I also need to match "4913" also.

Comment: @ButtleButkus Just noticed, I made a mistake there. It was `sw.?` Changed regex now. If you want to match 4913 as well, `^(.+\.sw.?|4913)$`

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan what does the question marks do in `^.+?\.sw.?$`? is it to make it match `foo.swp` and `bar.sw`

Answer (score 1):

try this regular expression

```
^.+\.sw[px]$
```

Comment: Works great but what about "4913"? I tried this but it doesn't work: ^.+\.sw?[px]$|^4913$